# Is it possible to include files via src but not allow by url?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I'm facing the following situation:

A major client wants to build a online platform whose files can be seen by the users but he wants the access via url impossible.

By other words: he wants `<img src="images/lorem_ipsum.jpg" />` to be stream the image but http://url/images/lorem_ipsum.jpg blocked.

So, at this point I found a solution but it's not satisfying:

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/images/lorem_ipsum.jpg" />
```

So... the main question, can we do anything using .htaccess to achieve the same purpose?

Comment: Read every image through the PHP script. Or google "hotlinking" to prevent it with your webserver.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really any way to do what you are asking. Sure you can base 64 an image but the reality is that doing so massively slows down your website load time. There is the prevent hotlinking .htaccess file hack but that doesn't stop anybody from spoofing your website referrer url. So long story short why would you bother? You can't stop people downloading/using your images.

Comment: True story, The client is being a pain in the ass with this subject. That's why I bothered to ask, probably something could eventually came up

Comment: They can be like that. Thing is I have never seen a image/video file online I couldn't download.